# Configuring Jetty for FastCGI has worked, but how to add virtual hosts?

Tags: virtualhost, php-fpm, wordpress, fastcgi, jetty

On [CentOS 7 Linux](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg07135.html) I have successfully followed the guide [Configuring Jetty for FastCGI](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configuring-fastcgi.html).

However the `$JETTY_BASE/webapps/jetty-wordpress.xml` file in the guide serves a *single* Wordpress installation located in `/var/www/wordpress`:

```
<New id="root" class="java.lang.String">
    <Arg>/var/www/wordpress</Arg>
</New>

<Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
<Set name="resourceBase"><Ref refid="root" /></Set>
<Set name="welcomeFiles">
    <Array type="string"><Item>index.php</Item></Array>
</Set>
```

while I have *several* virtual hosts, each with Wordpress installed in:

- /var/www/wordpress1 (www.site1.com)
- /var/www/wordpress2 (www.site2.com)
- /var/www/wordpress3 (www.site3.com)

Until now I was using Apache with the following `httpd.conf` (using localhost as the IP address, because Apache/Jetty are behind HAProxy):

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress1
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias *.site1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress2
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias *.site2.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress1
    ServerName site3.com
    ServerAlias *.site3.com
</VirtualHost>
```

How to translate the above Apache-config to Jetty IoC XML format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by reading the [Configuring Virtual Hosts](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configuring-virtual-hosts.html) document and creating 3 XML-files:

- $JETTY_BASE/webapps/site1.xml
- $JETTY_BASE/webapps/site2.xml
- $JETTY_BASE/webapps/site3.xml

With the following content at the top of each file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" 
    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler">

    <New id="root" class="java.lang.String">
        <Arg>/var/www/html/site1.com</Arg>
    </New>

    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
    <Set name="virtualHosts">
            <Array type="java.lang.String">
                    <Item>site1.com</Item>
                    <Item>www.site1.com</Item>
            </Array>
    </Set>
    <Set name="resourceBase"><Ref refid="root" /></Set>
    <Set name="welcomeFiles">
        <Array type="string">
                <Item>index.html</Item>
                <Item>index.php</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
```

And the rest of the file is as in the [Configuring Jetty for FastCGI](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configuring-fastcgi.html) document.